# Can't display SVG in AndEngine Anchor Center

Tags: svg, andengine

i'm having a problem with loading SVG texture to my project. This is what am i doing to load it.

```
public void onCreateResources(
        OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
        throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas mBuildableBitmapTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(
            this.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024,
            TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

    this.mTextureRegion = SVGBitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(mBuildableBitmapTextureAtlas, this,
                    "gfx/somethig.svg", 1024, 1024);

    try {
        mBuildableBitmapTextureAtlas
                .build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(
                        0, 0, 0));

    } catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
}

public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
        throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scene mScene = new Scene();
    Sprite suchSprite = new Sprite(1030, 550, this.mTextureRegion, this
            .getEngine().getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    mScene.attachChild(suchSprite);
    mScene.setBackground(new Background(0, 1, 1));
    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(mScene);
}
```

All what am i getting is just blank black rectangle...

Does anyone knows what is wrong?

thaks for your anwsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually forgot to load textureAtlas :)...

i just add this line under building texture:

```
mBuildableBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
```